# How to change the color of window frame on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, colors

I'm having trouble finding how to change the color of the window frame (header and border) on Windows 10. 
How do I change the color of what's yellow like on this person's computer?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will press the Windows Flag key [image] one time and then start typing in "*color settings*" until you see **Color Settings** appears at which point you will click on that to open up the options.

[image]

You will select the **Title bars** option to ensure it is checked, and then from the **Windows Colors** section, you simply select the color you wish to use.

[image]